# Refreshing a list of variables with one command

Tags: python, variables, refresh

I've got a collection of variables that depends on the values of another collection of variables and i need to be able to refresh the former collection with just one command. I had planned to use def (functions) to do this but I'm having problems with creating or changing variables inside of functions. Here's my failing code:

```
variable1 = 5
variable2 = 5
variable3 = 10

def refresh():
    variable4 = variable1 + variable2 + variable3
    variable5 = variable3 - variable2 / variable1
refresh()
```

What is a good way to get that functionality?

Comment: `variable4` and `variable5` should not be variables, they should be *functions*.

Comment: @roippi Then where would the returns of the functions be stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> python doesn't allow me to work with variables inside of functions it seems...

Sure it does. The problem is that Python assumes that when you try to assign to variables, you're trying to create *local* variables, unless you tell it otherwise. The way to do that is with the `global` statement:

```
def refresh():
    global variable4, variable5
    variable4 = variable1 + variable2 + variable3
    variable5 = variable3 - variable2 / variable1
```

The reason Python assumes local by default is that usually global variables are a bad idea. If you're just doing this for convenience at an interpreter prompt, it's probably reasonable as-is. But if not, you should probably take parameters and return values instead, like this:

```
def refresh(variable1, variable2, variable3):
    variable4 = variable1 + variable2 + variable3
    variable5 = variable3 - variable2 / variable1
    return variable4, variable5
```

Or possibly wrap up all these independent variables in a `class` so you can carry them all around together, with a method like this:

```
def refresh(self):
    self.variable4 = self.variable1 + self.variable2 + self.variable3
    self.variable5 = self.variable3 - self.variable2 / self.variable1
```

Another alternative would be to replace `variable4` and `variable5` with functions that you just call whenever you need the value.

If there's really a performance problem with calculating them over and over, you can use some form of caching with an explicit way to clear the cache—but in that case, making them methods in a class is again a good idea.

Or, maybe even better, make them `@property`s of a class, which lets them *look* like attributes but *work* like functions.

---

Here's an example of using a class instead of a bunch of separate variables:

```
class BunchOfStuff(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = 5
        self.variable2 = 10
        self.variable3 = 15
        self.refresh()
    def refresh():
        self.variable4 = self.variable1 + self.variable2 + self.variable3
        self.variable5 = self.variable3 - self.variable2 / self.variable1

stuff = BunchOfStuff()
print(stuff.variable4) # prints 30
stuff.variable1 = 10
print(stuff.variable4) # still prints 30
stuff.refresh()
print(stuff.variable4) # now prints 35
```

Or, if you want to get rid of the explicit `refresh` calls by re-calculating the value each time:

```
class BunchOfStuff(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = 5
        self.variable2 = 10
        self.variable3 = 15
    def variable4(self):
        return self.variable1 + self.variable2 + self.variable3

stuff = BunchOfStuff()
print(stuff.variable4()) # prints 30 -- note that it's a method, so we call it
stuff.variable1 = 10
print(stuff.variable4()) # prints 35
```

If you want `variable4` to look like a regular attribute, but act like a method, do this:

```
class BunchOfStuff(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = 5
        self.variable2 = 10
        self.variable3 = 15
    @property
    def variable4(self):
        return self.variable1 + self.variable2 + self.variable3

stuff = BunchOfStuff()
print(stuff.variable4) # prints 30 -- no need to call it, it acts like a variable
stuff.variable1 = 10
print(stuff.variable4) # prints 35
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

A problem is though that variable 1-3 will actually be more like 40 variables, and 4-5 will actually be 9 total variables. It's a pretty large amount of arguments.

Comment: @user3108546: Then you almost certainly don't want 40 separate variables, but a single list, dict, or class instance. See [this blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) and [this one](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html). (Combined with the need for a `refresh` function, the arguments for a class over the other alternatives seem pretty strong.)

Comment: @user3108546: Do you need an example to start you off, or are you ok with just the basic tip?

Comment: Yes, an example would be highly appreciated because I've never really worked with classes before.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce said variables that are needed in order to refresh as *parameters* to the function.

```
variable1 = 5
variable2 = 5
variable3 = 10

def refresh(var1_,var2_,var3_):
    var4_ = var1_ + var2_ + var3_
    var5_ = var3_ - var2_ / var1_
    return var4_, var5_

variable4, variable5 = refresh(variable1,variable2,variable3)

print variable4
print variable5
```

### What is now happening in your code

You are defining variables 1, 2, and 3 as before, only now you are passing them directly into the function. On that first line, `def refresh(var1_,var2_,var3)`, the statement is essentially saying:

```
var1_ = variable1
var2_ = variable2
var3_ = variable3
```

And then through the rest of the code, you can see that it does the same work. `var4_` and `var5_` are calculated, and then they are `returned` in a list. At the end, you are saying that:

```
variable4 = var4_ #20
variable5 = var5_ #9
```

The `print` commands at the end merely verify this, and the script I've provided gives you the code:

```
20
9
```

Does this answer your question? If not, feel free to comment and ask more (make sure to tag me with @jwarner112 so I know to come back!)

Happy coding!

Comment: sure enough this answers my question, but what if I'm working on a much bigger scale (instead of variables 1-3 i will have 40 variables and instead of variables 4 & 5 i will have 9 variables (each 9 having a different set of the first 40 as arguments))

Comment: I would use `tuples` or `lists`, in that case. Instead of `def refresh(var1_,var2_,var3)`, you would want either `def refresh(hereisalist_)` or `def refresh(hereisatuple*)`, where the list is just a list of 40 variables, or the tuple is just (var1_,var2_,var3_,...,var40_) and it is up to you to know which one on a scale of `[0]` to `[39]` to use on the inside. You would also have the function return a list or tuple, which would then get assigned on the outside similarly to how you have it assigned on the inside.

Comment: Using lists is an interesting idea, i should've thought of that sooner actually. And i would use 9 lists too (1 for each of the 9 variables in the function) so it's viable, but i'd _Never_ place a whole 40 values into a list or tuple. It'd be too much trouble to keep track of it i think.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user3108546: A `dict` is a nice way to get the best of both worlds—it combines all the values together into one variable instead of 40, like a `list` would, but it lets each value have a memorable name instead of just being #13, like using separate variables would. (A `class` or `namedtuple` are two other ways of getting the best of both worlds, with different advantages and disadvantages on top of a `dict`; it's worth learning about all three.)